# Error: No module named '_plotly_utils.importers' when import a module plotly for python

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I am working in a jupiter notebook using a conda environment.
I am trying to import a module plotly (library for Python) for plotting, but I get an error (see below).

```
from plotly import graph_objects as go

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-077f328b714a> in <module>
----> 1 from plotly import graph_objects as go

D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\__init__.py in <module>
     28 from __future__ import absolute_import
     29 import sys
---> 30 from _plotly_utils.importers import relative_import
     31 
     32 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_plotly_utils.importers'
```

I already did pip install plotly-utils.

CMD with conda environment give me this after pip list:

```
(base) C:\Users\Alex>pip list
Package                            Version
---------------------------------- -------------------
...
...
plotly                             4.9.0
plotly-utils                       0.0.3
pluggy                             0.13.1
ply                                3.11
prometheus-client                  0.8.0
...
...
```

But i still have this problem.
Where can i find and install the module **_plotly_utils.importers**?

Comment: Please Check this link https://community.plotly.com/t/no-module-named-plotly-utils/21090/2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/plotly plotly
```

if it doesn't work try this

```
pip install plotly
pip install cufflinks
```

Comment: Thank you!
It helped me. 
The library was imported successfully after `conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/plotly plotly`